# Not able to change tabs in react

Tags: reactjs

This is the code which I have written to prepare a tab component:

```
export class  Tabs extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'tab1'
    };
  }

  onChangeTab(value) {
    this.setState({ selectedTab: value });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      selectedTab
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <TabGroup value={selectedTab} onChange={this.onChangeTab}>
        <Tab value={'tab1'}>{'Tab1'}</Tab>
        <Tab value={'tab2'}>{'Tab2'}</Tab>
      </TabGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

It is displaying the tab1 and tab2 with default pointer at tab1 but when I try to switch by clicking on tab2 I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

Being new to react, not sure how this could be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are in class

You can solve this in a few ways

or

```
onChangeTab=(value)=> {
   this.setState({ selectedTab: value });
 }
```

or

add bind in this line

```
<TabGroup value={selectedTab} onChange={this.onChangeTab.bind(this)}>
```

or

in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'tab1'
    };
    this.onChangeTab = this.onChangeTab.bind(this);// add this line
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `this` in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: "tab1",
    };
    this.onChangeTab = this.onChangeTab.bind(this);
}
```

Or simply use arrow function:

```
onChangeTab = value => {
    this.setState({ selectedTab: value });
};
```